# xml value as ouptut from xslt with in HTML elements

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I think this question may be repeating from other place but I want to put it differently with the output that I need.

I have the below xml , I want to select the value of savings element for the category data with the Name element value is "Total" with in table td elements

I tried this xsl path "//ArrayOfCategoryData/CategoryData[Name='Total']//Savingsdollar/text()" where I couldnot see the output value

```
<IntervalReport>
    <ArrayOfCategoryData>
        <CategoryData>
          <Category>
           <Category>
             <Savingsdollar>0.00</Savingsdollar>
             <Savingspercentage>0.00</Savingspercentage>
             <Savingsusage>0.00</Savingsusage>
           </Category>
          </Category>
         <Name>Refrigeration</Name>
        </CategoryData>
      <CategoryData>
         <Category>
          <Category>
            <Savingsdollar>999.97</Savingsdollar>
            <Savingspercentage>0.00</Savingspercentage>
            <Savingsusage>9,998.04</Savingsusage>
          </Category>
         </Category>
        <Name>Total</Name>
      </CategoryData>
    </ArrayOfCategoryData>
   </IntervalReport>


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/IntervalReport">
    <html>
      <head>
     </head>
      <body>
    <div class="maindiv">
     <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style='border-left: none; border-bottom: none; width: 51px;'>
                              $ <xsl:value-of select="//ArrayOfCategoryData/CategoryData[Name='Total']//Savingsdollar/text()"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style='border-bottom: none; width: 29px;'>
                              <xsl:value-of select="//ArrayOfCategoryData/CategoryData[Name='Total']//Savingspercentage/text()"/>%
                            </td>
                            <td style='border-bottom: none;'>
                              <xsl:value-of select="//ArrayOfCategoryData/CategoryData[Name='Total']//Savingsusage/text()"/>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed as it starts off with a closing tag `</ArrayOfCategoryData>`. Can you amend it to show the XML you are actually using (if there are any namespace declarations, make sure to include these too!). Also can you show a complete sample of your XSLT that reproduces your issue, not just a fragment. Thank you!

Comment: actually its a Typo while writing here, my actual xml is like the way I corrected above now.

Comment: The XSLT you have posted does get results. See http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtj/1 . It may also help if you showed the output you are currently getting, and the output you expect. Thank you!

Comment: also I am facing a degree value problem 50°F/10°C is the xml value which after rendering from xslt the output is 50Â°F/10Â°C , it there any solution for this ?

Comment: The solution is to ask a whole new question, as there is nothing about degrees in this question. It's totally fine to ask new follow-up questions. Make sure to include your input XML, and the output you expect. Thanks!